# Make HTTP requests to .module file drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am trying drupal for first time. After going through several tutorials I came to conclusion that `.module` file is basically a php file with a different extension. My understanding for `.module` file holds true til I write functions and callbacks that carry operation well within the drupal site.

However I want to contact my module from my rails application. For this I'm using HTTP methods. I am sending `get` request to my module file which contains proper php code to send back an acknowledgment. But instead I am getting the whole file un-executed.

How can I get the `.module` file to execute its function by making a HTTP request? Or else, how can I include a proper php file from within the module file to do so?

Comment: you're trying to bypass drupal, basically. don't do that. it may be a .php file, but it's not intended to be called directly.

Comment: Does that mean we cannot make any request to modules directly?

Comment: no, but it means you don't point directly at a .module file.

Comment: Can you please suggest a workaround? I am sorry my understanding for drupal is almost nil.

Answer (score 1):

Do not directly call a .module file for one it will not work unless you overwrite .htaccess file. And it is very very unwise

Do the following

1. Create a menu item in ur .module with hook_menu
2. This menu item will point to a method in your module
3. In this method you can pretty much return what you want and in whatever format you want it(xml,json, html you name it).

Comment: A quick question: How to invoke this `hook_menu` method through http request?

Comment: hook_menu is a hook method which create url which can be accessed via http. It baiscially creates a url like http//mysite.com/my_page. which u can then call from your ruby script

Comment: Awesome. I'll try and confirm. Thanks a lot for pointing me to right direction :)

Comment: If you are trying to create someting similar to rest end point see this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4718/how-to-create-test-endpoint